# How can I get the value of it from html to php?

Tags: php, html

How can I get the value of information from html to php? with the calculation of Interest = Loan Amount * 5% (or 10%), Total Loan Amount = Loan Amount + Interest, Monthly Dues = Total Loan Amount / Number of Terms (6, 12, 24). What should write in php?

---

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang= "en">
    <head><title>Registration Form</title>
    <style>
       .Cn{
           text-align:center;
           color:#1e90ff;
           font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       }
       .add{
           color:black;
           font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       }
       .h1{
           text-align:center;
           color:black;
           font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       }
        table, th, td {
           border: 1px solid black;
           align:center;
       }
       table.center{
           margin-left:auto;
           margin-right:auto;
       }
       table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
       }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body> 
    <form action="LoanInformation.php" method="post">
        <h2 class="Cn">Loan</h2>
        <center class="add">blah City<br>
        Mobile Number: 12345678900 <br> Telephone:(08)9999999
        </center>
        <hr style="Width:100%;color:#dc143c">
        Borrower Information:<br>
        Name:<input type"text" name="name"><br>
        Address:<input type"text" name="address"><br>
        Contact#:<input type"text" name="contact">
        <h1 class="h1">Loan Amount</h1>
    <div>
        <table class="center">
            <tr>
                <th>Select Loan Amount</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name='r1' value="Php 5,000">Php 5,000</td>
            </tr>    
            <tr>    
                <td><input type="radio" name='r1' value="Php 10,000">Php 10,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <td><input type="radio" name='r1' value="Php 15,000">Php 15,000</td>
            </tr>    
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name='r1' value="Php 20,000">Php 20,000</td>
            </tr>    
                <td><input type="radio" name='r1' value="Php 25,000">Php 25,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Terms of Payment</th>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><input type="radio" name="r2" value="6 months">6 mos</td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="radio" name="r2" value="12 months">12 mos</td></tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="r2" value="24 months">24 mos</td>
               <tr> <th>Cooperative Officer</th></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="chckbx">Yes</td></tr> 
        </table>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="button">
    <center><input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" value="Clear All">
    </center>
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

here is the code i wrote in php but it's incomplete. some php is empty because i don't know what to code in there. in interest is loan amount multiply by 5%, the total amount is loan amount plus the interest and monthly dues is total loan amount divide by months in radio button choice.and if the "cooperative officer" checkbox is not selected the interest should be 10%.

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang= "en">
    <head><title>Registration Form</title>
    <style>
       .Cn{
           text-align:center;
           color:#1e90ff;
           font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       }
       .add{
           color:black;
           font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       }
       .h1{
           text-align:center;
           color:black;
           font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       }
        table, th, td {
           border: 1px solid black;
           align:center;
       }
       table.center{
           margin-left:auto;
           margin-right:auto;
       }
       table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
       }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h2 class="Cn">Loan</h2>
        <center class="add">blah City<br>
        Mobile Number: 12345678900 <br> Telephone:(08)9999999
        </center>
        <hr style="Width:100%;color:#dc143c">
        <h1 class="h1">Loan Information</h1>
        <table class="center">
            <tr><td>Date</td>
                <td><?php echo date('F d, Y'); ?></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><?php echo $_POST["name"];?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td><?php echo $_POST["address"];?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Contact</td>
                <td><?php echo $_POST["contact"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Amount</td>
                <td><?php if(isset($_POST['r1'])){
                    $amount = $_POST['r1'];
                    echo $amount;
                }
                ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Terms of Payment</td>
                <td><?php if(isset($_POST['r2'])){
                    $months = $_POST['r2'];
                    echo $months;
                }
                ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Interest (5%)</td>
                <td><?php  ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total Amount</td>
                <td><?php ?>;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Monthly Dues</td>
                <td><?php echo $_POST[""]?>;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <center>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> <br>
        <input type="submit" value ="back">
        </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please add your PHP code. Now you only show a HTML form. When the HTML form is submityed, you can get the data in PHP via the $_POST globals (for example)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make the value of your radio buttons with the amount of the loan pure integers (5000, 10000, ...), do the same for the duration of the loan (6, 12, 24).

After you can calculate the values like this:

```
$interest = isset($_POST['chckbx']) ? 0.1 : 0.05; // 10% interest rate if checkbox is checked, else 5%
$interestValue = $_POST['r1'] * $interest;
$totalAmount = $_POST['r1'] + $interestValue;
$monthlyDue = $totalAmount / $_POST['r2'];
```

You can format the money values using [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
$moneyValue = 'Php ' . number_fomat($value, 2, '.', ',');
```

Comment: thanks I have change the values of the radio buttons. and I just add "echo before the $amount and $months but "Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\Php\.php on line 76" upto line 78. idk why.